# Update Full Array values in one column

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, for-loop

I have a table with blog column in it and i want to add values from a array, my problem is that i need to insert one full array value in one column. Here is what i am trying ...

```
foreach($title1->find('tr') as $song){
    $name_a[] = $song->plaintext.'<br>';

    }
```

and trying to enter this array in column

```
for($i=0, $count = count($name_a);$i<$count;$i++) { 
$lyrics = array_push($name_a[$i]);  

$songs_data_update   = array( 
                'lyrics'     => $lyrics,
                'songs'      => $song_name

                );
        try {
                $STH = songs_data_update();
                $STH->execute($songs_data_update);
                }catch (PDOException $DBH){
                die($DBH->getMessage());
                }
}
```

i know this is wrong ... and its not working ... i want to add '< br >' in end of each row thats the reason i am making array to this. So how can i do this ... full array goes in one column

Comment: Do you want to use [http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php](implode), e.g. something like `$lyrics = join('', $lyrics);`?  This will turn the Array `$lyrics` into a string consisting of all its elements one after the other.

Comment: @dvijaz Thx Bro it worked ... but i have to take it out of for loop .... thx can u make it as answer so i can accept it ;)

Comment: OK but there might be a better way to do it: what does your `find` function do on the `$title1` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).  E.g.

```
$lyrics = join('', $lyrics);
```

turns the Array `$lyrics` into a string consisting of all its elements concatenated.